# Appropriate syntax for Initialising Python C-API container types (List Dict Tuple Set) in C++

Tags: python, c++11, types, python-c-api

I'm designing a C++ Python-wrapper.

I have an Object class to wrap a generic PyObject*, and I am providing constructors and conversion operators so that I can do things like:

```
// C++ type -> PyObject (of appropriate PyFoo_Type)
Object i{42}; // create a PyObject of type PyLong_Type
Object f{3.14}; // create a PyObject of type PyLong_Type

// PyFoo_Type -> C++ type
std::string s{f}; // convert PyObject to PyString_Type, then convert to std::string
```

I'm currently looking at how I might initialise containers: `PyDict_Type PyList_Type PyTuple_Type PySet_Type` (I think that's everything?)

It appears I can break this down into just 2 cases: `PyList_Type` and `PyDict_Type`. Because for `{PyList_Type, PyTuple_Type, PySet_Type}` I can initialise a `PyList_Type` and subsequently convert it.

My question is: **What C++ syntax should I provide?**

Seeing as it is my goal to open-source my project for public consumption, I need to pay attention to providing a usable interface that isn't going to jar with existing design patterns.

Everything that follows below is my thought process, and my own attempt to answer the question. I will separate it. Also, my apologies that this may be an open question (more than one solution).

---

**(THOUGHTS...)**

Let's say I want to initialise a list:

```
Object l{1,2,3,"four",5}; // notice each item may be of a different type
```

`std::initializer_list<Object>` would be one option, and it would implicitly typecast every argument to Object

But now what would one want `Object{1}` to yield? Probably a `PyInt_Type`. But the initializer_list constructor is going to overshadow/hide it.

And then dictionaries:

```
Object d{K1Type k1:V1Type v1, K2Type k2:V2Type v2, ... }; // ILLEGAL C++ syntax!
```

Again, key2 might not be the same type as key1, that's the great thing about Python.

In C++ I don't think there's any way to use `:`, but I could catch `{ {,}, {,}, {,} }` with `std::map<Object,Object>` or `std::pair`

So it seems to be the List that is the biggest problem.

The only thing I can think of this having a first argument specify type:

```
Object{ PyList_Type, 1,2,3,"four",5 };
Object{ PyDict_Type, k1, v1, k2, v2, etc };
```

This would have some advantage for typing out dictionaries, as extra braces cause clutter, although I should also allow for:

```
Object{ std::map<Object,Object> };
```

So I think my complete set of constructors-for-containers would look like this:

```
// list, tuple, set
Object( PyTypeObject type_, std::initializer_list<Object> args ) {...} 

// dict { {,} , {,} , ... } style
Object( std::map<Object,Object> ) {...} 

// dict { , , , ...} style (less typing)
Object( PyTypeObject type_, std::map<Object,Object> ) {...}
```

Then for symmetry I should provide:

```
// for everything
Object( PyTypeObject type_, Object& ob ) {...}
```

... Allowing the user to do something like `Object f{PyFloat_Type, 3}` (3 would normally get converted to PyLong_Type)

But wait! 3 is not going to be implicitly converted to `Object`, as implicit conversions only work for single-argument constructors.

```
Object i{PyFloat_Type, Object{3}}; // bit yucky
```

Maybe I should create a MakeLong function, so I can do:

```
Object f{ MakeFloat(3) };
```

But wait, can't I use the `std::initializer_list` constructor to my advantage here,

```
Object f{ PyFloat_Type, {3} };
```

And then I can code:

```
// list, tuple, set
Object( PyTypeObject type_, std::initializer_list<Object> args ) 
{
    // first convert args to a PyList_Type PyObject*, say l
    // if type_ ISN'T {PyDict_Type PyList_Type PyTuple_Type PySet_Type}
    //      x = l[0] (and assert len(l)==1) else x = l
    // then get Python-Runtime to convert x into "type_"
}
```

That is going to handle everything!

So first it would convert {3} into a list containing one PyLong_Type.
Then it will pull out the first (and only) element.
Then it will convert this into a PyFloat_Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution I tried was to use std::initializer_list as follows:

```
    Object( PyTypeObject& _type, std::initializer_list<Object> args )
    {
        if( &_type == &PyDict_Type )
        {
            Object dict{ PyDict_New() };
            for( auto p = args.begin(); p != args.end(); )
            {
                Object key{ *p }; p++; Exception::wrap( p != args.end(), "Dict init requires even # of args" );
                Object val{ *p }; p++;

                PyObject_SetItem( dict.p, key.p, val.p );
            }

            *this = dict;

            return;
        }

        // first unpack args into a PyList
        Object list{ PyList_New(0) };
        for( auto ob : args )
            PyList_Append( list.p, ob.p );

        if( &_type == &PyList_Type
         || &_type == &PyTuple_Type
         || &_type == &PySet_Type )
        {
            *this = list.convert_to(_type);

            return;
        }

        *this = list[0];
    }

    Object( const char c, std::initializer_list<Object> args )
    {
        if( c=='L' ) *this = Object{  PyList_Type, args };
        if( c=='T' ) *this = Object{ PyTuple_Type, args };
        if( c=='S' ) *this = Object{   PySet_Type, args };
        if( c=='D' ) *this = Object{  PyDict_Type, args };
    }
```

However, this makes for some seriously ugly syntax, as it fails to convert arguments to Objects, appearing to require:

```
 Object{ 'L', { Object{42}, Object{3.14}, etc. } };
```

So I settled on using a variadic argument:

```
    template<typename Foo, typename ... More>
    void unpack_to_list( Object& list, Foo&& foo, More&& ... more ) {
        PyList_Append( list.p, Object{foo}.p ); // I *think* PyList_Append expects a neutral pointer
        unpack_to_list( std::forward<More>(more) ... );
    }

    void unpack_to_list( Object& list )  { } // recursion terminator

    //template< Car car, Cdr ... cdr >
    template<typename ... Arg>
    Object( PyTypeObject& _type, Arg&& ... arg )
    {
        Object list{ PyList_New(0) };
        unpack_to_list( list, std::forward<Arg>(arg) ... );
        Py_ssize_t N = PyObject_Length( list.p );

        if( &_type == &PyDict_Type )
        {
            Exception::wrap( N % 2 == 0, "must supply an even number of arguments to dictionary" );

            Object dict{ PyDict_New() };

            int i=0;
            while( i < N )
                PyObject_SetItem( dict.p, list[i++].p, list[i++].p );

            *this = dict;
        }

        else if(
                & _type == & PyList_Type
             || & _type == & PyTuple_Type
             || & _type == & PySet_Type    )
        {
            *this = list.convert_to(_type);

            return;
        }

        else
            *this = list[0];
    }

    template<typename ... Arg>
    Object( const char c, Arg&& ... arg )
    {
        if( c=='L' ) *this = Object{  PyList_Type, std::forward<Arg>(arg) ... };
        if( c=='T' ) *this = Object{ PyTuple_Type, std::forward<Arg>(arg) ... };
        if( c=='S' ) *this = Object{   PySet_Type, std::forward<Arg>(arg) ... };
        if( c=='D' ) *this = Object{  PyDict_Type, std::forward<Arg>(arg) ... };
    }
```

This technique allows for a tidy lightweight usage syntax:

```
Object myList{ 'L', 42, 3.14, "foo", etc. };
Object myDict{ 'D', "key1", val1, "key2", val2, etc. };
```